# findManyToManyRowset exclude columns

Tags: php, zend-framework

how to exclude columns from findManyToManyRowset() method result?

```
$servers = $this->findManyToManyRowset(
                'Serverlog_Model_DbTable_Computer', 
                'Serverlog_Model_DbTable_Server');
```

$servers->toArray() gives me:

```
object(Serverlog_Model_Rowset_Computer)#458 (10) {
["_data":protected] => array(5) {
[0] => array(27) {
  ["id"] => int(462)
  ["name"] => string(10) "test"
  ["key"] => string(0) ""
  ["keyboard"] => int(1)
  ["mouse"] => int(0)
  ["serial_nr"] => string(10) "test"
  ["status"] => int(1)      
}
```

I tried to overload methods toArray() inherited from Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract and Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract, but nothing has changed.

```
class Serverlog_Model_DbTable_Computer extends My_DbTable_Model {

  protected $_name = 'computers';
  protected $_dependentTables = array('Serverlog_Model_DbTable_Server');
  protected $_rowClass = 'Serverlog_Model_Row_Computer';
  protected $_rowsetClass = 'Serverlog_Model_Rowset_Computer';  


class Serverlog_Model_Rowset_Computer extends Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract {
public function toArray() {
    foreach ($this->_rows as $i => $row) {
        $this->_data[$i] = array($row->_data['id'] => $row->_data['name']);
    }
    return $this->_data;
}

class Serverlog_Model_Row_Computer extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {
 public function toArray() {
    return array($this->_data['id'] => $this->_data['name']);
}  
}
```

I want to get result from $servers->toArray():

```
object(Serverlog_Model_Rowset_Computer)#458 (10) {
["_data":protected] => array(5) {
[0] => array(27) {
  ["id"] => int(462)
  ["name"] => string(10) "test"  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row objects are meant to be reflectional representations of the DbTable row structure. It is ambivalent behavior to be able to exclude fields from a Row object.